# Magento Cart, Newsletter

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart, newsletter

Magento ver. 1.7.0.0

We are currently using Magento and want to send Newsletters out. It has this build in. We have created templates and then when it gets moved into the queue it sticks there and does not get sent out at the appropriate time. There is no other way of sending the newsletter out immediately and there are no error messages to give you a clue as to why the situation has arisen.

Has anyone come across this and found a fix?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable cron for scheduled tasks in Magento.  Login to your server in ssh (putty), open your crontab;

```
crontab -e
```

and add this line to it;

```
*/5 * * * * php -f /path/to/magento/shell/cron.php
```

Obviously change /path/to/magento/ to the actual path on the server.

You can now also enable log cleaning in admin which sheds alot of db records which slows Magento down.

Hope this helps

T